# String's char value changed to Int

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I am working a string related problem, where few digits also exist. my job is to iterate all chars, identify those digits and perform an arithmetic operation. Finally return the modified string. but for this operation all chars are changing to Int.

Thanks

```
string str="Please Change 2015";
string str2=String.Join("", str.Select(x=> (x >= '0' && x <= '9') ?'9'-x: x).ToList()); 

Given Output: 8010810197115101326710497110103101327984
Required Output: Please Change 7984
```

Comment: working sample at https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qm2Cuj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or just

```
string str = "Please Change 2015";
string str2 = String.Join("", str.Select(x => char.IsDigit(x) ? (char)(9-(x-'0')+'0') : x).ToList());
```

**Ouput**

```
Please Change 7984
```

**Explanation**

```
-'0' // convert it from char to a number 
+'0' // convert it back to a char 
(char) // make sure we output characters again
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for a `StringBuilder` to me.  Append each non-digit character, perform your math on each digit character, output full string at the end.

**Note:** this assumes you aren't supposed to modify the input string but rather to return a new one.

See [my repl here](https://repl.it/@clarkitect/OpenCarefreeKeygens), or the code pasted below.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    const string testcase = "Please Change 7984";
    const string input = "Please Change 2015";
    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    input.ToList<Char>().ForEach(c => {
        if ('0' <= c && c <= '9')
            builder.Append('9' - c);
        else
            builder.Append(c);
    });

    var output = builder.ToString();
    var success = (testcase == output);

    Console.WriteLine($"output: {output}");
    Console.WriteLine($"success: {success}");
  }
}
```

**outputs:**

```
>>> Mono C# compiler version 4.0.4.0
>>> output: Please Change 7984
>>> success: True
```

Comment: Thanks @clarkitect, i like your answer as my expectations. But is there any way to do this program in a single statement in LINQ ? i mean why LINQ is not enough for this program.

Comment: we are using LINQ extensions: `.ToList` and `.ForEach` both.  The `StringBuilder` is really the way to make a new string if you're going to do this often.  If you have a _requirement_ to use `.Select` the other answers implement it that way at a cost of (varying) readability.